# using gtest with xcode

Tags: c++, xcode4.5, googletest

I'm trying to set up a c++ unit testing library on my computer and figured that google's gtest would be a good fit.

I am currently running mountain lion with the most recent release of xcode.

I have been attempting to follow the instructions found [here](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/XcodeGuide) but am running into an intresting problem.

I am opening the gtest project, building it, and even though xcode tells me that the build was successful, I cant seem to find the framework anywhere. any help on this subject would be highly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can add more information, such as console output of your build process?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

1. Get the code from https://github.com/dmonopoly/gtest-cmake-example
2. Run the cmake GUI in the usual way (I used version 3.0.0).  Hit "Configure", one of the prompts allows you to choose XCode generation.  Hit configure again, Enable the "test" config option, hit configure again (and maybe even once again), then hit "Generate".

You should now be able to find the XCode project in the build directory that you specified.  Open that project, and you will find the gtest source code, some demo test code, as well as a target for running the tests.