# How can cmake be used to create an XCode project that has a test target with clickable output

Tags: c++, xcode, c++11, cmake, googletest

There are some pages that explain how to use XCode with gtest directly (e.g. https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/XcodeGuide.md), but I want to be able to start from cmake and get a fully integrated result.  Cmake allows one to generate the XCode project.  I want the generated XCode project such that it properly integrates the tests (e.g. if a test fails, the output that displays the location in the source should be a click-able shortcut to that source code location).  How does one do that?

So far, I've succeeded in getting the XCode/gtest project going (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26051265/2727805), but not at the clickable output.